# Looking to get the full site URL

Tags: salesforce

I am looking to get the current site url in my apex class. I want the whole url, not just the domain Instead of https://google.com/ can it be something like https://google.com/page?something=something
I could only find how to put the domain without the full link. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the current URL of the Visualforce page you can use

```
PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
string currentUrl = pageRef.getUrl();

// Get or set query string parameters
string param1 = pageRef.getParameters().get('param1');
```

This only works in Visualforce.

When using Lightning, you should pass any additional parameters to the apex controller you need. You can use this JS to get the current page URL to send to the apex controller.

```
let currentUrl = window.location;
```

[PageReference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)